How to fix table header in Angular 9
I'm using angular 9 with angular material and tailwind.
How can I fix the form header so that the header follows when scrolling down the page?
<table @stagger mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort style="width: 100%;">

            <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; trackBy: trackByProperty">
                <ng-container *ngIf="column.type === 'text'" [matColumnDef]="column.property">
                  <th *matHeaderCellDef class="uppercase" mat-header-cell mat-sort-header>
                    {{ column.label }}
                  </th>
                  <td *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="column.cssClasses" mat-cell>
                    {{ row[column.property] }}
                  </td>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
</table>

Example 1
When I scroll down the header disappears
Example 2
I already tried to use sticky class:
class="sticky top-0 z-50"

And pure css:
.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white; /* Para que o cabeçalho não sobreponha o conteúdo */
  z-index: 1; /* Para garantir que o cabeçalho esteja acima das linhas */
}

What can I try to do this?
I hope I was clear;

You are almost there usually to fix headers, add the following classes to your  element and the header row :
see the header documentation: material_angular_header_docs
I have provide code to help below:
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="sticky-header uppercase" mat-sort-header>
  {{ column.label }}
</th>


Then to your html file
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="sticky-header"></tr>


OR
This would always work put each column name in an ng-container as shown below, then put all of them in a container <div class="table-container">
    

<ng-container matColumnDef="name_of_your_column" [sticky]="freezeColumns">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="name_of_your_column">
            content</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name_of_your_column}} </td>
</ng-container>


